# Using my own stopword list with gensim.corpora.textcorpus.TextCorpus

Tags: gensim, stop-words

In gensim 4.0 subclasses of gensim.corpora.textcorpus.TextCorpus apply a default preprocessing including remove_stopwords(). This function uses the stopword list stored in  gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS.

How can I replace this list with my own? I can do the following

```
import gensim 
gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS = frozenset({'aber', 'alle', 'allem', 'allen' })
```

and it works with gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopwords(s). So this works as intended:

```
gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopwords("aber alle lachten")
> 'lachten'
```

But the list is not used when I process my files using the class gensim.corpora.textcorpus.TextDirectoryCorpus (which is a subclass of TextCorpus). For example:

```
import os
os.mkdir('test123')
with open('test123/test.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('aber alle lachten \n allen gefallen \n')

corpus = gensim.corpora.textcorpus.TextDirectoryCorpus('test123')    

for text in corpus.get_texts():
    print(text)

> ['aber', 'alle', 'lachten', 'allen', 'gefallen']
```

I know that I can write my own subclass and overwrite the method to preprocess the files, but this seems like overkill for replacing a stopword list.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code for `gensim.corpora.textcorpus.py`...

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/textcorpus.py

...you can see that:

**First**, that module has its own `remove_stopwords()` function - which consults `gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS`, but (in the style of Python default parameters) only at the moment of the function's definition. (Also, somewhat confusingly, while this `gensim.corpora.textcorpus.remove_stopwords()` function has the same (module-unqualified) name as the other function in `gensim.parsing.preprocessing.remove_stopwords()`, it takes a *list-of-tokens*, while the other function takes a *space-delimited-string*.)

This behavior could probably be improved, with the benefit of easier understaning/customization, to respect that `STOPWORDS` variable's *current* value each call - but the way it's defined now, at the moment that function is defined (when your code imports the module), it 'captures' at the current value of `gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS`. If you then change that value, that function will still refer to the old set of stop-words.

**Second**, that the `TextCorpus` class (used by `TextDirectoryCorpus`), in its `__init__()` method for new-object initialization, will use this local `remove_stopwords()` (along with `remove_short()` as the default value of `token_filters`, if not otherwise specified. So: simply specifying your own `token_filters` would be enough to assert full control about what stop-ord removal is happening, without requiring any other new subclassing.

So, you've got 2 potential ways to get the behavior you want:

- replace the value `gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS` *before* the `gensim.corpora.textcorpus` module defines its functions. (This might be tricky given the way various Gensim imports may bring in other modules automatically, or it might be easy - I haven't checked.)
- Specify your own `token_filters` when initializing your `TextDirectoryCorpus` - so the previously-defined function that captured the older `STOPWORDS` isn't used. For example, it might be enough to just do:

```py
from gensim.corpora.textcorpus import TextDirectoryCorpus, remove_short, remove_stopwords

MY_STOPWORDS = frozenset({'aber', 'alle', 'allem', 'allen' }) 

def my_remove_stopwords(tokens):
    remove_stopwords(tokens, stopwords=my_stopwords)

corpus = TextDirectoryCorpus(
             'test123',
             token_filters=[
                 remove_short,        # same as default
                 my_remove_stopwords  # your corrected version
             ]
         )
```